# Golang request middleware library?

Tags: go

I'm using gorrilla mux for my mux for my routing setup.

Is there any open source library that will provide some sort of request middleware?

```
router.HandleFunc("/products", GetProducts).Methods("GET")
```

So currently I have the GetProducts function that will return the products etc.

But this is a REST api that I am building, so I have to handle things like loading the user, verifying the 'api token' for the request etc.

I don't want to do this for each and every method so I was hoping I there was some request middleware when I can do this before/after execution, along with adding things like `User`, `Permissions` to the context in each middleware function.

Comment: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/handlers

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Go Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) HTTP web framework that supports middlewares as well as you want:

Using middleware:

```
func main() {
// Creates a router without any middleware by default
r := gin.New()

// Global middleware
// Logger middleware will write the logs to gin.DefaultWriter even you set with GIN_MODE=release.
// By default gin.DefaultWriter = os.Stdout
r.Use(gin.Logger())

// Recovery middleware recovers from any panics and writes a 500 if there was one.
r.Use(gin.Recovery())

// Per route middleware, you can add as many as you desire.
r.GET("/benchmark", MyBenchLogger(), benchEndpoint)

// Authorization group
// authorized := r.Group("/", AuthRequired())
// exactly the same as:
authorized := r.Group("/")
// per group middleware! in this case we use the custom created
// AuthRequired() middleware just in the "authorized" group.
authorized.Use(AuthRequired())
{
    authorized.POST("/login", loginEndpoint)
    authorized.POST("/submit", submitEndpoint)
    authorized.POST("/read", readEndpoint)

    // nested group
    testing := authorized.Group("testing")
    testing.GET("/analytics", analyticsEndpoint)
}

// Listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
r.Run(":8080")
}
```